# When doing Moq in webapi, why my contentResult is always null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I was trying to set up my Moq for WebApi unit testing, but Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult) is always failed. Is that becasue I pass my mockList incorrectly?  Please help me, code as belowed

```
 [TestMethod]
  public void GetCEO()
    {

      // setting up the mock framework
      var mockRepository = new Mock<IUsersRepository>();
      List<Users> mockList = new List<Users>();
      {
          new Users
          {
              User = 1,
              FirstName = "TestFirstName",
              LastName = "TestLastName",
              Group = "CEO"
          };
      }
      mockRepository
     .Setup(x => x.GetCEOs())
     .Returns(mockList);

     var controller = new UsersController(mockRepository.Object);

     IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Get();
     var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Users>>;
     Assert.IsNotNull(mockList);
     Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
     Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
     var users = contentResult.Content;
     Assert.AreEqual(1, users.Count());
```

}

Please check my get action method

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/GetCEO")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var data=_repository.GetCEOs();
        if (data == null)
            return NotFound();
        else
        return Ok(data);

    }
```

My IusersRepositoy

```
    public interface IUsersRepository
{
    List<Users> GetUsers(int supervisor);

    List<Users> GetCEOs();
}
```

Comment: You're using `as` to cast the `actionResult`. `as` will result in null when the cast fails. I'd check the return type of `Get()` and see if your cast is correct.

Comment: I agree. What is `actionResult?.GetType().ToString()` just after you call `controller.Get()`?

Comment: Hey,Guys. Please help. I uploaded my Get  action method

Comment: Add a check for the http code first, if it's 404 you got your answer.

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuo `var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Users>>;`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The error is gone. But my assert.areequal is failed. It seems my mocklist object is not passed into mockRepostiroy.Object. And it did not show any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's cause the `as` casting is failing and resulting in `null`

```
actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Users>>
```

There is issue. per your edit your method definition is below

```
List<Users> GetCEOs();
```

With that you should cast to

```
actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Users>>
```

Yeah that's cause your code is full of error. It should be like below

```
  List<Users> mockList = new List<Users>()
  {
      new Users
      {
          User = 1,
          FirstName = "TestFirstName",
          LastName = "TestLastName",
          Group = "CEO"
      }
  };

  mockRepository
 .Setup(x => x.GetCEOs())
 .Returns(mockList);
```